# Fully customized Python Help Usage

Tags: python, customization, argparse

I'm trying to create a fully customized "help" usage with Python (which I plan to import into many programs that I want to have style consistency) but am having some trouble.

1. I don't know why my description is ignoring newlines...
   tried "" and '',
2. I can't get the ":" to occur after a /newline for the "...ARGS" lines, and obviously they look weird sitting on their own lines, and
3. I have no idea how to add the newline at the end.  Help please??

Here's a sample of what I am getting right now:

```
nameconstant version 1.0

USAGE:  myprog.py [constant text] <input.ext> <input.ext>

several lines of text describing my program.. because it will be necessary

___________________
COMPULSORY ARGS:
  input.ext
  output.ext

___________________
OPTIONAL ARGS:
  -v, --verbose  print debugging messages to terminal
  -h, --help
```

This is what I WANT it to look like:

```
nameconstant version 1.0

USAGE:  myprog.py [constant text] <input.ext> <input.ext>

several lines of text
describing my program..

because it will be necessary

___________________
COMPULSORY ARGS:

  input.ext
  output.ext

___________________
OPTIONAL ARGS:

  -v, --verbose      print debugging messages to terminal
  -h, --help
\n - not visible!
```

Here's the code I have working so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import sys 
from os import path
version = "1.0"

prog = path.basename(sys.argv[0])

class USAGEformat(argparse.HelpFormatter):
        def add_usage(self, usage, actions, groups, prefix=None):
                if prefix is None:
                        prefix = 'nameconstant version '+ version+'\n\nUSAGE:  '+prog
                return super(USAGEformat, self).add_usage(
                      usage, actions, groups, prefix)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False, formatter_class=USAGEformat, description='several lines of text\ndescribing my program..\n\nb
ecause it will be necessary', usage=' [optional args] <INPUT.ext> <OUTPUT.ext>')

parser._positionals.title = '___________________\nCOMPULSORY ARGS'
parser._optionals.title = '___________________\nOPTIONAL ARGS'

parser.add_argument('input', metavar="input.ext", type=argparse.FileType('rt'))
parser.add_argument('output', metavar="output.ext", type=argparse.FileType('wt'))
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', default=False, help='print debugging messages to terminal')
parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help', default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

What should I be doing differently or looking into next??  Thank you!  Any help is greatly appreciated..  I am new to Python.

Comment: To preserve newlines you'll need to use (subclass) one of the `RAW...` helpformatter classes, rather than their parent `HelpFormatter`.  While you are at it look at how they modify the parent.  The changes aren't big.

Comment: There is a convention for USAGE lines to have the optional arguments in square brackets. So I don't think you really want [input.ext] and [output.ext] on the first line and having them in COMPULSORY section.

Comment: @xhancar thank you, I guess have been doing that wrong for a while now and completely overlooked it because I thought it looked nice haha.  appreciated!  will be checking that to switch <> and [] in all of my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse
version = "1.0"

class USAGEformat(argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter):
    def add_usage(self, usage, actions, groups, prefix=None):
        if prefix is None:
            prefix = 'nameconstant version '+ version+' USAGE:  '
            return super(USAGEformat, self).add_usage(
                usage, actions, groups, prefix)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False, formatter_class=USAGEformat,
   description=\
'''several lines of text
describing my program..

because it will be necessary''')

gp1 = parser.add_argument_group('___________________\nCOMPULSORY ARGS')
gp1.add_argument('input', metavar="input.ext", type=argparse.FileType('rt'))
gp1.add_argument('output', metavar="output.ext", type=argparse.FileType('wt'))

gp2 = parser.add_argument_group('___________________\nOPTIONAL ARGS')
gp2.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', default=False,
      help='print debugging messages to terminal')
gp2.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help', default=argparse.SUPPRESS)

parser.print_help()
```

produces

```
2156:~/mypy$ python stack47118098.py 
nameconstant version 1.0 USAGE:  stack47118098.py [-v] [-h]
                                                  input.ext output.ext

several lines of text
describing my program..

because it will be necessary

___________________
COMPULSORY ARGS:
  input.ext
  output.ext

___________________
OPTIONAL ARGS:
  -v, --verbose  print debugging messages to terminal
  -h, --help
```

`RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` preserves the formatting of the description.

I used the `'''...'''` for the description just to make the code look nicer; that's not important.

I substituted `argument_groups` for your renaming of the existing groups.  Your way works fine, but I think mine is what the developers intended.

`HelpFormatter` formats the various pieces, with a generous use of `\n` between them, and then ends up stripping out duplicates (including the end).  So we'd have to identify and modify the relevant method (`format_help`).

You've made some changes on the `usage` line since I started my answer.

I agree with the comment that required arguments are shown, by convention, without the `[]`.

I got this usage because the line, with prefix, is too long.  So it split it, and put the positionals on a second line, lined up with the optionals:

```
nameconstant version 1.0 USAGE:  stack47118098.py [-v] [-h]
                                                  input.ext output.ext
```

If I set

```
prefix = 'USAGE:  '
```

then usage is

```
USAGE:  stack47118098.py [-v] [-h] input.ext output.ext
```

We'd have to look at how it does wrapping and indenting to get the usage to your specs.

### edit

In [importing custom python modules.. why do only some elements carry over?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119468/importing-custom-python-modules-why-do-only-some-elements-carry-over)

I explain that the help formatter is created fresh each time you ask for a help or usage.  Defining the `parser` sets the formatter class, but does not create a formatter.  That means that any global variables that the formatter class uses will get their values as runtime rather than setup.

For example, `version` is global (to the module).  It is initially '1.0' and this is the value that appears in the usage.  But if I add to the end of the above script:

```
version = '2.0'
parser.print_help()
```

the usage line changes to:

```
nameconstant version 2.0 USAGE:  stack47118098.py [-v] [-h]
                                                  input.ext output.ext
```

If I import this script with:

```
import stack47118098 as pp

print('===========')
print(pp.version)
print(pp.parser)
pp.parser.print_help()

pp.version = '3.0'
pp.parser.print_help()
```

the first help (after import) uses the '2.0' version that was in the file.  But the second help uses the newly defined `version`.

To change something like the `description` of the parser, I have to use

```
pp.parser.description = 'New short description'
```

That is, I'm modifying an attribute of the existing object.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!  Alternate syntax and commentary on what the developers intended appreciated btw.  =)