# importing custom python modules.. why do only some elements carry over?

Tags: python, class, import, module, argparse

I need to create a python module that many scripts need to ultimately import from:

- Custom arg parsing to set format and constant args (i.e. my verbose and help args, and everything visually pleasing/consistent across scripts)

My custom module is currently working independently and I'm satisfied enough to move forward for now, but I can't seem to import it into another script properly.  THAT module imports another module (ver.py) defining a simple variable constant with no issues (a version code I want to exist in only one location).  But when I try to import that file into another (e.g. myexecutable.py) and add code for parsing additional arguments, it fails.  Also, I have _ _init__.py in the dir which contains all of the files I'm working with right now.

This code has changed so much and I can't get it back to a "partially working" state, but I can get it to have no errors.  Here's what's not throwing errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import par as pp  ##par.py is my working parsing code

pp.preq.add_argument('input', metavar=" INPUT.ext", type=argparse.FileType('rt'))
pp.preq.add_argument('output', metavar=" OUTPUT.ext", type=argparse.FileType('wt'))
```

Of note, I am hoping to define the 'description' and 'usage' in the executed file, not the imported file.  Here's a subset of what the imported file (par.py) has:

```
class USAGEformat(argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter):
        def add_usage(self, usage, actions, groups, prefix=None):
                if prefix is None:
                        prefix = 'nameconstant '+v.VERSION+'\n\nUSAGE:  '+prog
                super(USAGEformat, self).add_usage(usage, actions, groups, prefix)

parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False, formatter_class=USAGEformat)

preq = parse.add_argument_group("___________________\n++ COMPULSORY ARGS")
```

When I try to add in anything more with ArgumentParser, it doesn't recognize my USAGEformat class.  At some point I got my script to recognize it partially, and take my defined usage but not my defined description or compulsory arguments.  Can't figure out what I did though..

Why are my variables only working when importing when they are simple:

```
VERSION = "v1.0"
```

but not when they are more complex, and why are my classes not carrying over either?  I'm assuming I'm missing some basic understanding of how this works and failing to figure out what that is?  I've been teaching this language to myself with tutorials/Google because I'm not a computer scientist, and some direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's always a point posting your code. If it's too messy, clean it up. Please post a [mcve]. There is no reason why `version` would be importable but `parser` wouldn't. It's impossible to tell what your mistake is without seeing your code.

Comment: Hey @SSS it would be helpful, when you post the actual pain points: How declare you the things you want to import and how are you importing them.

Comment: @Rawing Well my intention was primarily to get some direction so I know if there's something I need to know, before editing then posting code if I can't get further, because I've realllly confused myself and don't know if it's worth getting my code back to something less desperate without more knowledge..  But that is a helpful start.  Follow-up questions before I revise and add my code:  should classes work as well as variables?  Is there any foundational concept regarding module importing that I might be ignorant to?

Comment: @SSS Yes, classes should work. Imports don't care about the data type. Everything you've defined (or imported into) your module should be importable. (As long as its name doesn't start with an underscore, e.g. if you define `_foobar = 5` then `_foobar` wouldn't be importable.)

Comment: @Rawing Thank you, that is so helpful to know.  I will try to get this back to a partially-working version and revise my question with my code once I get there.  =)

Comment: I revised my post and added some code.

Comment: Since `par` already imports `argparse`, don't import it again here. Here use `pp.argparse.FileType` etc.  Modifying variables/globals in the imported module is tricky.  It's best to define things as functions and classes, and pass new values as arguments.  Use `argparse.py` as good model of an importable module.

Comment: More of this code in his previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118098/fully-customized-python-help-usage

Answer (score 0):

Your previous question and code:

[Fully customized Python Help Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118098/fully-customized-python-help-usage)

With `import par as pp`, the all variables, classes and functions defined in that module have to be accessed with the `pp.` prefix.  Thus `pp.parser` is the parser object that was created on import.  `pp.preq` is one of the argument groups.

`pp.USAGEformat` is the custom formatter class.  But a formatter, an object of this class is not created when the `parser` is created nor when `par` is imported.  A formatter is created from the specified class when you ask for `help` or `usage` ('-h', `pp.parser.print_help()`).

(edit) This was wrong:

> > This formatter will take globals variables like `version` and `prog` from the current namespace (the importing one), not the `pp` one.

The formatter still takes `version` from the imported namespace.  But I can change that with:

```
pp.version = '3.0'
```

(see my edit in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47118317/901925)

You can test this behavior in `pre` itself by changing `version` at the end of the file and doing a new `print_help()`.  You'll see a change in the display.

`pp.parser` on the other hand is created on import.  You could modify `pp.parser.description`, the attribute that was set on creation.  Setting or changing `pp.description` doesn't do it.

When you do `parser.print_help()`, it calls `parser.format_help`, which in turn calls `parser._get_formatter`.  That method uses `parser.formatter_class` to create a `formatter` object, which is then 'filled' and 'executed'.  There's a lot of flexibility in this approach, but it can be confusing.